# Multi-tenancy with theming support

Tags: google-app-engine, multi-tenant

We are a building a Google app engine application with multi-tenancy and we expect that different tenants would want to change the look and feel of the app to their own corporate identity.   Any best practices for supporting themes with multitenancy on GAE?

Comment: This question would be better phrased from the point of view of whatever software you are using to build your web-application/interface. Eg, customised CSS, selection of template styles, replaceable images. I would think this has very little to do with the App Engine framework itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing themes is just one of many things you might like to let each tenant customize.  Providing per-tenant customizations should be straightforward as long as you can differentiate between your tenants.

One way to cleanly identify tenants is to have each access your app via their own subdomain (e.g., yourapp.theirdomain.com) or one you provide (e.g., theirname.yourapp.com).  Details on this approach was discussed in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135961/running-google-app-engine-application-on-multiple-customer-domains).