# Google app engine: Is it possible to allow users to add their own domain for a Multitenancy app?

Tags: google-app-engine, multi-tenant

I have been researching on how to let users add their own domain with GAE application.

The closest things that I got are:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/

https://cloud.google.com/dns/getting-started

[Running Google App Engine application on multiple customer domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135961/running-google-app-engine-application-on-multiple-customer-domains)

But I'm quite confused. So my questions are:

Say my app is myapp.com and I have a user with myapp.com/?name_space=user1. User1 has a domain called user1.com and want to forward myapp.com/?name_space=user1 to user1.com.

Is it possible to use cloud dns to modify the CName and A records to let users to forward myapp.com/?name_space=user1 to user1.com?

What are the options here? I've heard about dnsmadeeasy is a possible solution, but I'm not sure if it'd work. Because that means you need some api to modify the A record of dnsmadeeasy?

Can anyone give me some directions, tutorials or ideas? Any help will be grateful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135961/running-google-app-engine-application-on-multiple-customer-domains -- pretty good descriptions how to get user's domain to work with your app, than just set namespace according to domain name used for requests -- done.

Comment: wait, it requires user to use Google Apps control panel (the google app engine control panel if I'm not mistaken.) Or does it mean to use Google app for business for mapping the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom domain for App Engine through Google Domains.

With the domain registered through Google Domains, they provide an interface to point the domain to a particular App Engine ID using Google Synthetic Records.

More info on Google Domains can be found at:

https://domains.google.com/about/features.html

You can then point user1.com to your APP_ENGINE_ID.

Google Domains at this time is in Beta - but they have been sending invites out.  I have successfully used this to host a custom domain on one of my app engine accounts.

One thing to note, https isn't currently supported using the custom domain and an issue has been created.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8528

Comment: wow, I know google would have solutions to it. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks very much!